# Do not send GET request on clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, node.js

[EDIT]
I have the following link:

```
<a href="" class="undo_feedback">Undo</a>
```

I am performing an ajax request on clicking the link:

```
$('table').on('click', '.undo_feedback', function(e){
    // some code here
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'_method': 'delete'},
      url: //some url
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

It gives the error `cannot GET '//some url'`. The POST request is performed successfully. How can I get rid of this error?
I have tried using `return false`, `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but none of them seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Put an `alert("test");` above `// some code here` to check the function is being called.  Is it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table').on('click', '.undo_feedback', function(e){
   // some code here
   e.preventDefault();    
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      method : "delete",
      url: //some url
   });
});
```

put `e.preventDefault();` in above

i hope this help

Comment: I have tried that too, unfortunately that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable delete_url

```
$('table').on('click', '.undo_feedback', function(e){
    // some code here
--> delete_url = '/mydir/mydelete.php'; <--- LOOK HERE
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {'_method': 'delete'},
      url: delete_url,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Personally I prefer using the jQuery.post way instead of going via the ajax...

```
jQuery.post(delete_url,
                {
                _method : 'delete'
                }
            ,
            function(data)
                {
                window.alert(data);
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you assign url to the delete_url

Try this

```
//assign url to the variable
var delete_url="google.com/post";
$('table').on('click', '.undo_feedback', function(e){
// some code here
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {'_method': 'delete'},
  url: delete_url,
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why add an answer that already exists? Is there any benefit I'm missing?
Also, why declare the variable outside the function scope?

Comment: lolz sorry, i saw that after i posted. If you want me to delete it, i can. :)